# LINQ filter by attribute nested in 3 lists

Tags: c#, list, linq, nested, filtering

I am kind of new to working with LINQ and ran into a problem which I can't seem to solve.

So I basically need to filter on an attribute of an object that is nested inside three lists. The Data (as a JSON) looks as follows:

```
  [
   {
      "userName":"John",
      "resourceTypeUserVms":[
         {
            "name":"Administration",
            "description":null,
            "resourceUserVms":[
               {
                  "policyUserVm":{
                     "policyName":"admin",
                     "priority":0,
                     "metaHash":"abc123",
                     "policySetName":"Admin",
                     "policySetDescription":""
                  },
                  "accessType":"Administration",
                  "accessDescription":null,
                  "metaData":"{\"Name\":\"Admin\"}"
               },
               {
                  "policyUserVm":{
                     "policyName":"test",
                     "priority":0,
                     "metaHash":"abc123",
                     "policySetName":"Test",
                     "policySetDescription":""
                  },
                  "accessType":"Administration",
                  "accessDescription":null,
                  "metaData":"{\"Name\":\"test123\"}"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Database",
            "description":null,
            "resourceUserVms":[
               {
                  "policyUserVm":{
                     "policyName":"read_x",
                     "priority":0,
                     "metaHash":"def456",
                     "policySetName":"Test",
                     "policySetDescription":""
                  },
                  "accessType":"read",
                  "accessDescription":null,
                  "metaData":"{\"Server\":\"srv\",\"Name\":\"test\"}"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "name":"Configuration",
            "description":null,
            "resourceUserVms":[
               {
                  "policyUserVm":{
                     "policyName":"readc",
                     "priority":0,
                     "metaHash":"ghi789",
                     "policySetName":"Configurations",
                     "policySetDescription":""
                  },
                  "accessType":"read",
                  "accessDescription":null,
                  "metaData":"{\"Name\":\"ServiceName\"}"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

So I basically have a User with x amount of ResourceTypesUserVms and those ResourceTypes have x ResourceUserVms.

I need to filter on the attribute "metaData" inside of the ResourceUserVms. So if for example enter "Admin" into the filter bar, I want to get something like this in return:

```
[
   {
      "userName":"John",
      "resourceTypeUserVms":[
         {
            "name":"Administration",
            "description":null,
            "resourceUserVms":[
               {
                  "policyUserVm":{
                     "policyName":"admin",
                     "priority":0,
                     "metaHash":"abc123",
                     "policySetName":"Admin",
                     "policySetDescription":""
                  },
                  "accessType":"Administration",
                  "accessDescription":null,
                  "metaData":"{\"Name\":\"Admin\"}"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I have found some solutions online suggesting I do something like this:

```
filteredUsers = users
        .Where(x => x.ResourceTypeUserVms
        .Any(x => x.ResourceUserVms
        .Any(x => x.MetaData.ToLower().Contains(value))))
        .ToList();
```

However, this does not yield the result I want.

I got the expected result by doing this (unclean code ahead):

```
foreach(var user in users)
        {
            foreach(var resourceType in user.ResourceTypeUserVms)
            {
                foreach(var resource in resourceType.ResourceUserVms)
                {
                    if (resource.MetaData.ToLower().Contains(value))
                    {
                        filteredUsersTemp.Add(
                            new UserUserVm
                            {
                                UserName = user.UserName,
                                ResourceTypeUserVms = new List<ResourceTypeUserVm>(
                                    new ResourceTypeUserVm[] {
                                        new ResourceTypeUserVm
                                        {
                                            Description = resourceType.Description,
                                            Name = resourceType.Name,
                                            ResourceUserVms = new List<ResourceUserVm>(
                                                new ResourceUserVm[]{ resource }
                                                )
                                        }
                                    })
                            }
                            );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me figure out a nice, clean way of doing this using LINQ!

Comment: what does the LINQ result in? Also, have you considered setting up dictionaries?

Comment: The LINQ returns the right user, but all ResourceTypes and Resources of that user get returned, not only the one that has the filtered value. No, I have not considered dictionaries. In what way do you think I could use them?

Comment: In order to only return the relevant ResourceTypes and Resources, you need to mutate those lists. LINQ's `.Where` doesn't do that, it affects which items from the root-collection are returned, it doesn't not alter the items themselves. You can return something different than the original item with LINQ's `.Select()`, but in order to mutate the object you probably need to [deep clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects) it and alter the `resourceTypeUserVms` property. Really what this needs is separate methods that do these tasks and call those methods in the LINQ.

Comment: @Snoopy111 that is because the linq you have is returning users that have your search term. You would need to use a Select in your LINQ if you wanted to specify what data to return. A dictionary is similar to using LINQ but the key would be what you want to search by and is good for large data sets. You can create a dictionary of dictionaries as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, you need to filter ResourceUserVms by MetaData as well.

So, firstly, get all users that have ResourceTypeUserVms that have ResourceUserVms that have MetaData (==value). You actually did it.

Then you can get rid of MetaData-useless ResourceUserVms.

```
   filteredUsers = users
            .Where(x => x.ResourceTypeUserVms
            .Any(x => x.ResourceUserVms
            .Any(x => x.MetaData.ToLower().Contains(value))))
            .ToList();

filteredUsers = filteredUsers.Select(x=>{

    x.ResourceTypeUserVms = x.ResourceTypeUserVms.Select(y=> {

       y.ResourceUserVms = y.ResourceUserVms.Where(s=>s.MetaData.ToLower().Contains(value)))).ToList();

       return y;

    }).ToList();

return x;

}).ToList();
```

Comment: Your `.Select()` skipped the `ResourceTypeUserVms`, edited this :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that almost worked. Had to add 
x.ResourceTypeUserVms = x.ResourceTypeUserVms.Where(z => z.ResourceUserVms.Count() > 0).ToList();
x;
So that I don't get the empty ResourceTypes returned. That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

```
from user in users
from resourceType in user.ResourceTypeUserVms
from resource in resourceType.ResourceUserVms
where resource.MetaData.ToLower().Trim().Contains(value)
```

Also, it is recommended to use `Any()` instead of `Contains()`.